# Bootstrap 3 image responsive height not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this div:

```
<section id="categorias">
 <div class="container content-section">
  <div class="row">
     <div  class="col-md-3">
        <img class="img img-responsive" src="img/catmusica.png"></img>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="img/catpaisajes.png"></img>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="img/catgrafiti.png"></img>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3" >
        <img class="img-responsive" src="img/catpoly.png"></img>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
```

That looks like this:
[image]

And I want to maintain the 4 columns or at least 2 above and 2 below when I shrink the window but this happens:
[image]

I have only bootstraps css.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also add grid system classes for smaller screens - col-sm-3 and col-xs-3. See following code:

```
<section id="categorias">
 <div class="container content-section">
  <div class="row">
     <div  class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        <img class="img img-responsive" src="img/catmusica.png"></img>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="img/catpaisajes.png"></img>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="img/catgrafiti.png"></img>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" >
        <img class="img-responsive" src="img/catpoly.png"></img>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
```

[working example](https://jsfiddle.net/gajuu77h/)

If you want to have only 2 columns on smaller screens then you need to apply this classes on div wrapping images:

```
<div  class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
   <img class="img img-responsive" src="img/catmusica.png"></img>
</div>
```